# When adding responsive-img img is no longer center with text-center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {
    padding-top:40px;
}
[class*="panel-body"]{
    min-height: 250px;
}
.glyphicon {
    font-size:60px;
}
.section-desc {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
}
.section-padding-mobile {
    padding-right:10%;
    padding-left:10%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">WA Nexus</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Create</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="/login/" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Sign In</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron col-lg-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>A Center For Worship Team<br />Planning And Scheduling</h1>
            <a href="/create/" class="btn btn-info">It's Free, Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <img src="/images/venues.png" />
                    <h4>Mobility</h4>
                    <p>WA Nexus was built on the idea of being on the go. You can setup any venue or worship setlist on your phone or tablet.</p>
                    <p><a href="">read more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <img src="/images/setlists.png" />
                    <h4>Teams and Venues</h4>
                    <p>We understand that trying to manage multiple bands for several venues can be a little tricky. We make it as easy as possible for you.</p>
                    <p><a href="">read more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <img src="/images/members.png" />
                    <h4>Members</h4>
                    <p>Members are vital to your church and service. You can assign each member to particular venues and setlists to make it easier for them.</p>
                    <p><a href="">read more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down text-center"></i>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header text-center" id="mobility">
            <h2>Manage Worship With Mobility</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center section-padding-mobile">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/mobility.png" />
                <p class="section-desc">We built WA Nexus from the ground up to be as optimized for mobile as it can be. In fact we thought of mobility first before anything. One of the greatest things we pride ourselves on is anything you can do on a desktop you can do on a mobile phone or tablet. We designed our system to match any need with any device.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down text-center"></i>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header text-center" id="mobility">
            <h2>Manage Worship Teams and Venues</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center section-padding-mobile">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/managebility.png" />
                <p class="section-desc">We understand that managing multiple services, members and venues takes time, we strive to make that as easy as possible for you. Our system makes it so easy for you to quickly add, remove and assign members to particular venues and setlists with just a few clicks. As well you can assign members to particular venues to make it easier for them to know their assignments.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down text-center"></i>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header text-center" id="mobility">
            <h2>Your Team Members Are Vital</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center section-padding-mobile">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/musicians.png" />
                <p class="section-desc">Team members are what make your service run, making it as easy as possible for them is what we do. Our system was built to make it as easy to understand for the simple man. When users log into their portal they are given a screen with just what they need. Why cloud their screen with so many options. You have the power to assign user rights for almost anything in WA Nexus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For what ever reason when I apply the `class="img-responsive` to my `<img>` the `text-center` no longer works on just the image. It aligns left while the `<p>` is still aligned to the center. Can seem to figure out why.

If I remove the `img-responsive` the image will align back to the center.

Answer (score -1):

img responsive has default css to uncenter and img. If you add text-center or center-block to the images parent it will work again

Comment: but the parent div already has text-center and it does not work or am I miss understanding you

Comment: you must have specified something  somewhere else to uncenter it because I plopped your code into code pen and the image was center http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYPXMZ

Comment: you dont have the bootstrap css included in that pen

Comment: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css paste this into the external css files box under the gear icon in the css section

Comment: That is weird we pasted the same thing and got 2 different results

Comment: in the pen you linked to, bootstrap is not included. See mine for reference

Comment: I meant I link to that on my webpage already, so weird why its not working

Comment: if you wrote custom css, something in there must be overriding it. Also I just noticed that you have not specified column width. After each 'row' you must specify a column before adding content. div.row>div.col-xs-12 will be a full width colum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74020/discussion-between-cesar-bielich-and-brian-mccall).